# Aurelia for.repeat wait spinner

Tags: aurelia

I have a really simple test case where I get a large list of Json entries say 2000 items. I simply want to display all these items on one page.
(Forget about whether that is a good design or not).

I have a standard spinner specified in my index.html that is displayed when loading the page and changing pages. However, the spinner stops and the page is displayed before the for.repeat loop completes.

What is the best way to handle this. I have tried to add a new spinner that page just for the for.repeat but there does not seem to be a way to know when the loop completes. I have tried using TaskQueue without success.
I could use a setTimeout as a dirty hack but I would like to know the correct way to handle this kind of thing.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you could use the `isBound` property described here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/binding/latest/interface/Binding.  Or, set a variable in your constructor (`bindSpinner = 1;`) and then unset it in your `attached()` lifecycle method (`bindSpinner = 0;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this would work:

```
export class LongDataList {

  constructor() {
    // start the spinner
    this.bindingSpinner = 1;
  }

  attached() {
    // stop the spinner
    this.bindingSpinner = 0;
  }

}
```

And in your template, something like this:

```
<template>

  <!-- spinner -->
  <span if.bind="bindingSpinner">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg"></i>
  </span>

  <!-- List of records -->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr repeat.for="record of records">
        <td>${record.user_username}</td>
        <td>${record.user_password}</td>
        <td>${record.p_fname}</td>
        <td>${record.p_lname}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</template>
```

Finally, if you want the spinner to appear in a different module, you could either bind the property from the parent component:

```
<long-data-list binding-spinner.bind="parent-binding-spinner"></long-data-list>
```

Or you could use Aurelia's `eventAggregator` to communicate the events to start and stop the spinner.  The first one is simpler, however.

Comment: I tried this approach before. The attached method gets called before the list gets rendered. The result is the spinner basically does not display as it gets stopped almost immediately.

Comment: Ok. Marking this as correct (You were first). Really all the answers were correct. My problem was I had a call to await this.getData(); in the activate() method and I was then trying to stop the spinner in attached(). I had to get the data in attached as well.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Gist for you based on the answer of @LStarky which shows how the spinner works.

I guess your problem is, your data is available directly and hence, the spinner disappears immediately. In my example, data is loaded from a remote location. During that time, the spinner is shown:

https://gist.run/?id=75d5ba1e321a918ee16366f7c2c4d0f2

This is the important point:

```js
export class App {
  bindingSpinner = 1;
  data = [];

  attached() {
    this.bindingSpinner = 1;
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').then(response => {
      // stop the spinner
       return response.json()
    }).then(data => {
      this.data = data;
      this.bindingSpinner = 0;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `activate()` life-cycle hook. If you return a promise in the `activate()`, the page will only be shown when process is completed. For instance:

```
activate() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    this.items = 50000;
    res();
  });
}
```

Self-Explained Running Example https://gist.run/?id=eb239baf7255bfe1c613be1dbbe44939

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem could be that the *rendering* of the list items takes too long.  When working with really long lists like this, you might benefit from virtualization, using the [aurelia-ui-virtualization](https://github.com/aurelia/ui-virtualization) package.

Install the package via JSPM

```
jspm install aurelia-ui-virtualization
```

Load the package:

```
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .plugin('aurelia-ui-virtualization');
```

and simply replace your `repeat.for` binding with `virtual-repeat.for`.  The actual rendering of the page should now be immediate, compared to when trying to iterate over a large list of items.